# How did the book find the basis for the kernel of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the question:
[image: This is the question]

This is the solution (How did they get vectors v1 and v2?):
[image]

Comment: The kernel of the transformation should be atleast $2$ dimensional..jast reduce the matrix in rrec form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They put the matrix in reduced row echelon form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&2&3&4\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&2&3\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1&-2\\0&1&2&3\end{bmatrix},$$
 whence the solutions are 
$$x=z+2t,\quad y=-2z-3t$$
This shows $\ker A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf R^2$. The image of the canonical basis of $\mathbf R^2$ is $(\vec v_1,\vec  v_2)$.